# Report Viewer 10 - CSS Issue

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari, report-viewer2010

I'm new to reporting services and having trouble getting a report to render correctly on my ASPX page. I'm using **MS Report viewer 10** using with **asp.net 4.0**.

Earlier my toolbar was not rendering correctly in Chrome & Safari

[image]

so after some R&D, i found & applied below script for the same

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () { fixReportingServices('divReport'); });

    function fixReportingServices(container) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) {
            $('#' + container + ' table').each(function (i, item) {
                if ($(item).attr('id') && $(item).attr('id').match(/fixedTable$/) != null)
                    $(item).css('display', 'table');
                else
                    $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
            });}}
```

so my toolbar problem got resolved :)

[image]

but after applying above so now im facing other CSS issue. now my page number is overlapped by report content. :(

[image]

SSRS Report

[image]

Any Suggestions Appreciated !!

Comment: have you put in relative positioning?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast yeah...its in relative position.

Comment: What about using clear? And is the page number called as a footer outside of the entire contents?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast.. what tht clear? for your reference i also uploaded that ssrs report image.

Comment: Is the page number the last thing to be called in your code?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast yeah.. tht expression is page number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy crap.. resolved by created below script.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () { fixToolbar(); });

    function fixToolbar() {
        $("#ctl00_ReportViewer1_Toolbar table").each(function (i, item) {
            $(item).css('display', 'inline-block');
        });
    }
```